# How can I delete this border in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There's like a Gray Outline containing these boxes, does anyone can help me delete / not show those gray lines?

Entered in Inspection Mode inside Chrome and im not abble to figure out, where is the parameter to edit to remove that outline.

I'm using Shopify editor, but will like to have better software to do these changes. Also the Original code is from this site, and the DEV is: Steve Meredith

https://codepen.io/steveeeie/pen/NVWMEM

Thanks,
LC

[image]

CSS:

```
max-width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-left: 3px;
}  

:root{
  --background-dark: #FFFFFF;
  --text-light: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  --text-lighter: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  --spacing-s: 8px;
  --spacing-m: 16px;
  --spacing-l: 24px;
  --spacing-xl: 32px;
  --spacing-xxl: 64px;
  --width-container: 1200px;
}

*{
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

body{
  height: 100%;
}

.hero-section{
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-image: #FFFFFF;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: var(--spacing-xxl) var(--spacing-l);
}

.card-grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: var(--spacing-l);
  grid-row-gap: var(--spacing-l);
  max-width: var(--width-container);
  width: 100%;
}

@media(min-width: 540px){
  .card-grid{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); 
  }
}

@media(min-width: 960px){
  .card-grid{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); 
  }
}

.card{
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.card:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 150%;
  width: 100%;
}

.card__background{
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: var(--spacing-l);
  bottom: 0;
  filter: brightness(0.75) saturate(1.2) contrast(0.85);
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: center;
  trsnsform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
  transition: 
    filter 200ms linear,
    transform 200ms linear;
}

.card:hover .card__background{
  transform: scale(1.05) translateZ(0);
}

.card-grid:hover > .card:not(:hover) .card__background{
  filter: brightness(0.5) saturate(0) contrast(1.2) blur(20px);
}

.card__content{
  left: 0;
  padding: var(--spacing-l);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.card__category{
  color: var(--text-light);
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin-bottom: var(--spacing-s);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.card__heading{
  color: var(--text-lighter);
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  line-height: 1.4;
  word-spacing: 100vw;
}
```

HTML:

```
section class="hero-section">
<div class="card-grid"><a class="card" href="#">
<div class="card__background" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0855/3802/files/59f7d87736e4c.jpg?v=1602082250');"></div>
<div class="card__content">
<p class="card__category">Download PDF</p>
<h3 class="card__heading">FiberClick Instruction Manual</h3>
</div>
</a> <a class="card" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0855/3802/files/BTCSBBWWOCL-1P.pdf?v=1602082225">
<div class="card__background" style="background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1109541/pexels-photo-1109541.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=750&amp;w=1260');"></div>
<div class="card__content">
<p class="card__category">Download PDF</p>
<h3 class="card__heading">FiberClick Datasheet PDF</h3>
</div>
</a> <a class="card" href="https://beyondtech.us/collections/fiber-cleaners">
<div class="card__background" style="background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/442154/pexels-photo-442154.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=750&amp;w=1260');"></div>
<div class="card__content">
<p class="card__category">Beyondtech.global</p>
<h3 class="card__heading">Purchase from Beyondtech</h3>
</div>
</a><a class="card" href="https://www.amazon.com/Fiber-Optic-Cleaner-Compatible-Connectors/dp/B086Q17M98/ref=sr_1_8?dchild=1&amp;keywords=fiber+cleaner+beyondtech&amp;qid=1602082414&amp;sr=8-8">
<div class="card__background" style="background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/4560039/pexels-photo-4560039.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=750&amp;w=1260');"></div>
<div class="card__content">
<p class="card__category">Amazon.com</p>
<h3 class="card__heading">Amazon Product Page</h3>
</div>
</a>
<div></div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make its outline property none.

```
.card {
  outline: none;
}
```

But if you do that, don't give styles to

```
.card:focus{
  // maybe the same style as :hover state
}
```

in order to achieve a better UX.

**EDIT**

After I see your pen, I made 2 changes.

```
.card{
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  outline: none; // this is new
}

// I add :focus selector here
.card:hover .card__background,
.card:focus .card__background {
  transform: scale(1.05) translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: I used your suggestion but the gray lines are still showing.

Comment: In this case, it's the outline of another element. But on Codepen, I don't see any outline, after I made the changes.

Comment: yes! me too! however is showing on my Shopify Page... maybe something from another code?